# Can Xcode run straight from source control without install

Tags: xcode, macos

I am managing a build lab and have several products/branches to provide service to and I would like my build machines not to be specialized to any one product/branch.

The scenario I would like to have is that souce and all tools needed to build it are checked into source control and just sync and build with some prep/env setup before hand via script.

This is very doable with Visual Studio and many other tools.  Is it possible with Xcode?  Has anyone gotten a scenario like this to work?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘without install’?

Comment: You can automate builds with `xcodebuild(1)`. There are a few questions on Stack Overflow about it.

Comment: What I mean and the scenario that I am after is.

Comment: oops.  1) machine goes down.  2) replace with new machine 3) point it to source control 4) sync sources 5) run build scripts and build.  No Xcode install. Xcode is included in source control as part of my sources.  My build scripts launch and setup the environment for Xcode to be able to run from within my source code enlistment.  The scenario is also good for new hires.  Just point machine to source control, sync, build, and you are up and running.

Comment: Biggest issue I am trying to fix is that we have several versions of software that we support and I would like any given Mac build machine to build any given project that requires any given toolset.  The Mac machine itself is clean with no tools corrupting its setup.  The projects/branches can live side by side on disk with their respective toolsets.  The machine can be used to build any of them and if it goes down it can be replaced, re-sync'd and no further setup is required for the build machine.

Comment: @Mez I see. Apart from cloning a hard drive with Xcode pre-installed (i.e., it wouldn’t be part of the managed source code repository), I don’t really know whether that’s possible. You might want to send an e-mail to the xcode-users mailing list at http://lists.apple.com (some Apple folks monitor that list) and/or post your question to http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can automate installs using Apple Remote Desktop: http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/

Answer (score 0):

Some system components may need to be shared. Since this is such an atypical scenario, documentation will not be readily available. I would suggest asking on the Xcode-users mailing list that Apple maintains, as you may get a more certain answer.

Comment: Thanks I'll do that.  As Apple products/platforms become more popular I suspect this situation will become more typical.  It is the most cost effective way to run a build lab. I'm also looking into virtualization to accomplish the same thing.  But would prefer to not to if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if this possible. There are 2 possible ways I know of.

**First, which we also follow in our project:**

1. Source code for all projects in checked in the common repository.
2. A remote server is configured to point to this repository.
3. Remote server has XCode pre-installed. A pre-written scripts with steps including workspace cleanup, checkout fresh code, build the code, package the output is already feed into the remote server. Of these XCode related commands are using `xcodebuild`.
4. Remote server can be configured in 3 ways: a) Build the source code on every checkin, b) Build the source code triggered by user, c) Scheduled building of the source code.
5. Build results are emailed to the configured email addresses.

**Second way is the [continuous integration with MAC OS X server](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/200-Adopting_a_Continuous_Integration_Workflow/adopt_continuous_integration.html).**

Just in case you found out the exact system config you are looking for, please post an answer here to enlighten us as well.